# Как вывести первую не пустую строчку из файла?

Tags: c#

Имеется файл, в котором есть множество строк, как пустых, так и с текстовым значением. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести в консоль только первую не пустую строчку?

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines("C:/File.txt").FirstOrDefault(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));`

Comment: или так `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Length > 0)` или если надо пробелы игнорить, то `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Trim().Length > 0)`

Comment: @aepot Есть же `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` для пробелов, зачем велосипед изобретать? )

Comment: @CrazyElf ну скажем, null оно тут не может быть, но да, без разницы, можно и так.

Comment: Всем спасибо)
И еще вопрос, а возможна реализацию без применения LINQ?

Comment: Можно, конечно - переберите через `foreach` строки и как будет нужная, так печатайте и делайте `break` циклу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> а возможна реализацию без применения LINQ?

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        break;
    }
}
```